# Electromagnetic induction circuit

Tags: diodes, circuit-analysis

*In the picture below we see 3 LEDs in a parallel circuit. When the switch is closed only LED 2 and LED 3 are on. LED 1 isn't on because it's a diode in the opposite direction. You observe what happens when the switch is closed and opened by opening the switch first and then closing it. Explain:*

- Which LED(s) are on for a short while after opening the switch;
- Which LED(s) are not on for a short while after closing the switch.

p.s. - I probably made some mistakes in translation. Here is the image of the circuit:

[image]

**My Problems**:

I can't answer any of these questions. I know for sure they have something to do with electromagnetic induction. But I'm having trouble grasping what will happen in these situations. Can someone help? I know that if a switch is open and closed there will be induction for a short time.

Comment: Isn't this a picture from a textbook, and the explanations to help you answer the questions can be found nearby?

Comment: @JYelton So you assume that every single individual can make every question flawlessly if he just has a bunch of formulas? No, of course not. Also, no.

Comment: @JYelton Not all textbooks work that way. In fact most of the text books I've used don't have detailed explanations nearby.

Comment: Also the pictured circuit of how to kill an LED.

Comment: Starter clue: google "back-emf".

Comment: @AndrejaKo as long as the switch isn't closed too long, there is nothing here that will kill the LED.

Comment: @ZafarS We get a lot of questions that are "homework questions" where the asker doesn't show any effort, but merely wants an answer for free. I was gently trying to ask whether the adjacent/surrounding text was present, and if so, whether you were having trouble understanding the explanation or not.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Sounds like you've had some poor quality textbooks! Generally illustrations and figures are referred to by some text that accompanies it for detail.

Comment: @JYelton My main problem is that I've never really 'understood' circuits. I used to study for test regarding those a day before, get an A and then just never look back and forget. Now we are studying EM and circuits aren't discussed again, so I am sort of in trouble. I however certainly understand your concerns.

Comment: @ZafarS No problem! The community here has a great many helpful people who can explain things well. Hopefully someone will be able to assist you.

Comment: @JYelton Well few chosen pictures did have some explanation nearby in my introductory EE book. Most of the time, illustrations would be referenced by their number and the distance between text and picture would be 20 to 30 pages. No illustration index of course. But it was written by an academician professor doctor, so it must be good. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inductors resist changes in current. To change the current in an inductor, you must apply a voltage. If you remove the voltage, the inductor will make its own voltage so that the current can keep flowing. Of course, making this voltage requires energy, and as that energy moves out of the inductor and into something else, the current will eventually reach zero, when there's no energy left in the inductor.

So, when the switch is closed for a while, there is a current in the inductor. When you open the switch, that current must keep going. Where can it go in this circuit, if its prevented from going through the battery by the open switch?

[image: switch closed] [image: switch open]

A diode allows current to flow only in one direction. It's no mistake that their schematic symbol looks like an arrow. If the switch is opened, there is only one place for the same current to keep flowing, and that's through LED1 and LED2. It will keep flowing here, even without help from the battery, until all the stored energy in the inductor has been transferred to the LEDs.

Comment: Well if I'm correct, the current can flow to either the switch or to LED 1 or LED 3. LED 3 won't turn on because of the diode, but LED 1 will turn on. Is this correct?

Comment: @ZafarS not really correct. Current can't flow "to the switch" if the switch is open. There must be a closed loop for any current to flow. Imagine the electricity flowing out the + end of the battery, through the inductor, through the switch, and back into the - of the battery. Which way is the electricity flowing in the inductor? If the switch is now open, how can electricity continue flowing through the inductor, considering that it can flow only one way through a diode, and you need a complete loop for it to flow?

Comment: It first goes from the left to the right.. but for it not to go to the switch it must go back from right to left?

Comment: @ZafarS: don't think about current going _to_ things. Think about current going _through_ things. There must be a closed loop for current to flow. You are right about the current flowing left to right through the inductor. There is one other closed loop around which current can flow that way, which doesn't go through the switch. Where is it?

Comment: I am sorry, this is embarrassing. But I'd say it can also go through LED 3. It can't go through LED 1 because of the diode..

Comment: @ZafarS everyone had this problem at some point. I've added two pictures, which should be good for at least two thousand words.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7145/discussion-between-phil-frost-and-zafars)

Comment: I can't possibly thank you enough, kind sir! I have one tiny remaining question, which is; what is the difference between LED 1 and LED 2 and 3? 2 and 3 seem to have sparks coming off of them or something, I haven't found an explanation on the internet.

Comment: @ZafarS: i think that's just to indicate that those LEDs are illuminated. It's correct, when the switch is closed.